# Adding CSRF token for window.location.href

Tags: javascript, security, csrf, csrf-protection, window.location

I have used `window.location.href`several places in my javascripts. Is there any generic way to add CSRF token to all of them?

> Since the window.location is an object and `window.location.href` is
>   one of its properties, we can't override it.
>
> Writing a common function something like below and routing all the
>   instances would be more manual and time consuming.

```
addCSRFAndProceed(url);
function addCSRFAndProceed (url) {
    window.location.href = url + getCSRFTokenAndValue();
}
```

**Backend code**
Here is the code for setting the CSRF cookie from my backend.

```
$_COOKIE['CSRFTOKEN'] = '123456';
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="redirect-button" onclick="TriggerRequest()">
```

**Javascript code**

```
function TriggerRequest() {
    window.location.href="www.mysite.com/?index.php&from=desktop";
}
```

I have different functions which use `window.location.href` and expecting a generic solution to append token to the url because it will be hectic to manually append in all the functions.

Comment: you should generate the csrf token on the backend (assuming you are not talking about node.js) and you could put it in the header if you want to have a "standard" place to get the token. However do you need csrf for redirects? Isn't it better to use it for forms?

Comment: I'm using plain javascript. I have created the CSRF token and saved that in the cookie. I agree that **it is better to use forms and also we may not need CSRF for redirects**.
But unfortunately my backend logic to check the CSRF token doesn't have more intelligence to separate different types of requests and ended up fixing from the front end.

Comment: but how would client side generated csrf tokens protect you? *"never trust the client"*

Comment: I have created the CSRF token from the backend and saved that in the browser cookie. I'm trying to append that backend generated CSRF token in the cookie in all my requests from the client and authenticate the same in the backend. If matched, let the request proceed, otherwise stop them.

Answer (score 0):

Let me speak from a laravel as a backend situation (just for 1 line relevant in my example, because the token has to come from somewhere)

```
<meta id="csrf" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

would output a csrf token in a meta tag with the `id` csrf right?

Well using and modifying your redirect code would work like:

```
addCSRFAndProceed(url);
function addCSRFAndProceed (url) {
    window.location.href = url + '?token=' + getCSRFTokenAndValue();
}

function getCSRFTokenAndValue() {
    return document.getElementById("csrf").getAttribute('content');
}
```

You also should write code for your backend that checks the query string parameter `token` and only return the requested page then. (server side validation)

**pseudo code (still don't know your backend)**

```
if ($query_string_array['token'] == 'accepted token') {
    return view:page;
} else {
    return error: token does not match;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this will work but I need to redirect numerous places to use `addCSRFAndProceed()`. Is there any other generic and dynamic way to perform something like `window.location.href = window.location.href + getCSRFTokenAndValue()`?

Comment: Using a Ajax call? That way you get multiple